# Need latest Java in Linux environment

Tags: debian, java, linux-mint

I need some help with Java in a Linux environment.  **Quick background:** we have Verizon FIOS and some of their services require use of their web site.  We experienced all kinds of random web site failures, which one of their techs finally narrowed down to problems with Java.  According to their tech, the latest version of Java is required for their web site to work properly (and since they constantly "improve" their web site, Java needs to be kept current).

We have three computers, running Windows, Linux Mint 17, and Debian Wheezy.  Updating Java on the Windows machine was not a problem.  After updating to the current release (SE7 U71), the web site problems cleared up.  The Linux machines are another matter and the more I research, the more my head spins.

**Windows Java vs. Linux equivalent:**  It isn't clear how what is offered for Linux matches up version for version.  The official Java download site offers four Linux downloads, two identified specifically as RPM and two not.  The instructions for the two not labelled as RPM are for distros that use RPM.  However, there are also some options to install manually from a tarball or compile your own, which might also apply to other distros (not clear).  There is an Ubuntu link under "other flavors", which leads to an OpenJDK page.  This is an "open-source implementation of the Java SE Platform" with a different numbering system.  This is paired with the IcedTea browser plugin (with another version numbering system), and it isn't clear how the combination of OpenJDK and IcedTea match to a specific Java release.

To complicate matters further, there are a number of different Java-related programs in addition to the JRE, such as the JDK, which I would think would be needed only for development but apparently some scripts need it.  The collection of Java files offered in Windows doesn't match the collection offered for Linux, so it isn't clear how the functionality of the components relate.  The Linux program managers have a long list of Java-related files, some of which vary by release, so it isn't clear what the collection of needed files is.

Let me clarify that I am **not** looking for answers to all of these questions, my objective is not to become a Java expert.  I provide this information only to demonstrate that I have made a serious attempt to research and solve this but it has simply led to more confusion.  Hopefully, there are readers who are familiar with Java and Linux who already know the answer and can bypass all of the confusing detail.

**Linux file versions:**  Both of the Linux machines appear to be using IcedTea rather than Java.  The Mint computer has IcedTea V1.5 dated April and the latest version available for Debian is  V1.4.  I looked at getting newer files from other repositories but can't find newer compatible versions.

**The problem:**  If the latest version of Java is required, how do I accomplish that in Linux?  The latest available versions of IcedTea don't cut it.  So the basic questions are:

- Is there a way in Linux to handle a web site that requires the latest version of Java?
- What do I need to do that?
- Where do I get it for Mint and Debian?
- How do I install it?

For the benefit of others who may have the same issue, feel free to post answers that require Linux proficiency.  However, I'm looking for a newbie solution if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install the Java Runtime Environment and the Java web browser plugin in Linux. However, as you noticed, the proprietary Oracle JRE is not available in the Debian or Ubuntu repositories. Oracle revoked the ability for Linux distributions to redistribute Java packages in 2011 (see [Ubuntu's](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2011-December/001528.html) and [Debian's](http://sylvestre.ledru.info/blog/2011/08/26/sun_java6_packages_removed_from_debian_u) notifications).

This leaves you with two primary options for installing Java on Linux:

1. Use [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) with the [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page) plugin. OpenJDK is an open-source Java runtime. IcedTea provides an open-source web browser plugin for use with OpenJDK, which can run Java applets in the browser. These both can be installed from the Debian and Ubuntu repositories. As you noted, OpenJDK may not provide full compatibility with the official Oracle Java runtime.
2. Use the Oracle Java runtime. This requires downloading Java from [Oracle's website](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp). For Debian and Mint, you would want the non-RPM packages. Then you can follow the instructions provided by Oracle to [install Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#Java%20for%20Linux%20Platforms) and [setup the Firefox plugin](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#enable).

If you want to stick to using packages from the Debian/Ubuntu repositories, I would recommend checking that you have the latest openjdk-7-jre package installed. Debian and Ubuntu both show the latest version of this package as 7u71, which is on par with the current latest release of the Oracle runtime.
You should also verify that the IcedTea for Java 7 package is installed (icedtea-7-plugin). Finally, you should verify that the older Java 6 packages are removed (openjdk-6-jre and icedtea-6-plugin).

If this fails, and the website you are trying to access requires features specific to the Oracle Java runtime, you will need to manually install the Oracle JRE.